# How to remove a key from account permissions?

Tags: accounts, permissions, keys

When I imported eos account into Exodus wallet it automatically updated my account permissions and added a second active key. I want to remove this key from my account. 
Does anyone know how?

```
        active     1:    1 EOS59P16Z7znbs6xjNX3Sf1TVZJ2gLsgmc9bPr3BLQbno6H8DcHsm, 1 EOS6nKk4qHJEjYGQCHzrC5DxJYaSwUQga7ZvdrVeBgTURq4HBG3Ha
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to eostoolkit to do that.  Enter the public key you'd like to keep, set owner as parent, your account name, then keep the threshold at 1 and sign the transaction.

> Remove a permission Specify the Permission and Parent, and leave a
>   single Authority row empty with the default Weight of 1.

Link: https://eostoolkit.io/account/advanced